# sum-aggregate function with non-unique values

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a set of documents with a structure like:

```
<DOCUMENT>
    <AMOUNTS>
        <ELEMENT>
            <AMOUNT>10.00</AMOUNT>
            <INFO>
                <CODE1>132</CODE1>
                <CODE2>022</CODE2>
            </INFO>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT>
            <AMOUNT>10.00</AMOUNT>
            <INFO>
                <CODE1>132</CODE1>
                <CODE2>121</CODE2>
            </INFO>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT>
            <AMOUNT>15.00</AMOUNT>
            <INFO>
                <CODE1>156</CODE1>
                <CODE2>121</CODE2>
            </INFO>
        </ELEMENT>      
    </AMOUNTS>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I’m looking to do various sums of the **AMOUNT** element so I’ve put a Path Range Index on the `DOCUMENT/AMOUNTS/ELEMENT/AMOUNT` element hoping to use the `sum-aggregate` function. However I’m seeing an issue when using the `cts:sum-aggregate` function when the sum involves documents that contain more than one **AMOUNT** element with the same value.  To illustrate the issue I’m seeing assume the XML above is stored at the '`/DOCS/DOC1.XML`' uri.  I then run the following xQuery to get the sum of all the **AMOUNTs** in the document. I'm doing the sum in two different ways and getting two different results:

```
(
  fn:sum(doc('/DOCS/DOC1.XML')/DOCUMENT/AMOUNTS/ELEMENT/AMOUNT),
  cts:sum-aggregate(
      cts:path-reference("DOCUMENT/AMOUNTS/ELEMENT/AMOUNT"), 
      ("any"),
      cts:document-query('/DOCS/DOC1.XML')
  )
)
```

The `fn:sum` function gives 35 and the `cts:sum-aggregate` gives 25.  The sum-aggregate function is only including one of the **10** values in the sum.

I think I’m doing something wrong but I can’t figure out what, can someone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2):

After reading the answer from wst I confirmed that the type of my index was decimal and then played around with the options a bit and found that adding "item-frequency" as an option to the sum-aggregate function solved my issue. I don't completely understand the nuances between "item-frequency" and "fragment-frequency" in relation to the sum-aggregate function but the following xQuery works like I expect it to causing both sums to return the same value.

```
(
  fn:sum(doc('/DOCS/DOC1.XML')/DOCUMENT/AMOUNTS/ELEMENT/AMOUNT),
  cts:sum-aggregate(
      cts:path-reference("DOCUMENT/AMOUNTS/ELEMENT/AMOUNT"), 
      ("item-frequency"),
      cts:document-query('/DOCS/DOC1.XML')
  )
)
```

Comment: Interesting. `item-frequency` typically is used to indicate sort order by number of items in the index vs number fragments (documents). Did you try explicitly defining the type as `decimal`?

Comment: `fragment-frequency` means it counts the number of fragments in which a particular value occurred, regardless of how many times it occurred in that fragment. `item-frequency` really counts occurrences themselves, so yes, `item-frequency` was what you were looking for. And yes, `fragment-frequency` is the default: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:aggregate

Answer (score 1):

Is your path index a `string` type or a number (`float`, `double`, etc.) type? I wouldn't expect this to work at all with strings, but maybe it is, and I don't see you passing a option to set the type to a number (`("any", "type=double")`).

String indexes combine identical (according to the collation) values into a single entry and increment the entry's `cts:frequency`. If `sum-aggregate` does work over string indexes (and I don't see anything in the documentation to suggest otherwise), that could explain why the duplicate value is only counted once.